# Why does electrons only acquire certain energy levels around an atom?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, atomic-physics, schroedinger-equation, orbitals, discrete

According to Bohr's hypothesis electrons can exist only at certain special distance from the nucleus only on certain particular orbits which is determined by Planck's constant, how does reach to this conclusion and what's the experiment behind it?

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/65636/2451 and links therein.

Comment: This is an excellent and very helpful answer: https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/735149/313612. And you can see the four visible Balmer lines in the spectrum (third figure) I show here: https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/768678/313612.

Comment: thanks for the help guys